# ZF3 - Class 'Zend\Json\Json' not found

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view, zend-framework3

In zf3 while trying to use JsonModel I get error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend\Json\Json' not found in
>   \vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\Model\JsonModel.php:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably didn't include zendframework/zend-json. You can do this by running this in your terminal:

```
$ composer require zendframework/zend-json
```

zend-json, as many other components, is a suggested package when zend-view is installed. But since there are many more [suggested packages](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/blob/master/composer.json) you might have missed that message.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. In the earlier versions this package was default so i dint think that this would be the issue.